# Fast load/save multidimensional array

Tags: c#, file, serialization, multidimensional-array

I need to quickly store/load possibly large `ushort[,,]`, `byte[,,]` or `double[,,]` array.

I have tried naive approach simply scanning the array element by element into `FileStream fs`:

```
for (p = 0; p < Planes; p++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            fs.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(array1[p, y, x]), 0, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

I have replaced this loop with `BinaryFormatter`, which performs better:

```
bf.Serialize(fs, array1);
```

I ran a small benchmark storing and then loading  3 x 1024 x 768 array of doubles 10 times with the following results:

naive approach: **10 628 ms**

BinaryFormatter approach: **8 722 ms**

***Is there any faster way? Using pointers? Serializing the array to one-dimensional and then flushing to file?***

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The binary formatter will be about the fastest thing I can think of, but you'll need to provide more code to outline what you've tried along those lines including # of elements tested because I would think that serializing one graph to file would be significantly faster compared to iterating through each element.

Comment: @StevePy I am actually working with photographic images, so the arrays are usually something like `ushort[3,1440,2160]`. The `BinaryFormatter` is very fast though I think is agnostic about the data structure. This is why I am wondering if there is a faster way exploiting the known format of the array (I am interested just in storing elements, the format and array size is known beforehand).

Comment: Your loop code could maybe be optimized but that won't change the I/O times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MemoryStream` to write data, and then `copyTo` your `FileStream`

```
ms.copyTo(fs)
```

It will speed up your IO operations with hard drive

Comment: Serializing to `MemoryStream` and then copying it to `FileStream` actually took twice the time than using `FileStream` alone. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Libor yes it may looks strange but it can really speed up by optimize your file IO operations

and just have second idea - use `BinaryWriter` instead `BitConverter.GetBytes`

Comment: Thanks for the `BinaryWriter` suggestion. I have actually did a benchmark and the BinaryFormatter+FileStream method is still fastest. Adding MemoryStream slows it down more than two times.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after several experiments the `BinaryFormatter` with `FileStream` is the fastest solution I found.

I have tested the following alternatives without improvement in speed:

- write to `MemoryStream`, then copy it to `FileStream`
- wrap `FileStream` in `BufferedFileStream`
- use `BinaryWriter` in naive loop instead of `BinaryFormatter`